# How to do comparison between two values in a String, based on there indexes

Tags: java

I have a String `String str = "ABC|123|5.00|#ABC|567|10.00"`;
Here `"ABC|123|5.00|"` and `"ABC|567|10.00"` are two strings but they come together.
I have to split this String, based on "ABC"; Find the indexes of "ABC", then find the highest amount from these two strings, by comparing them. I am able to find the indexes of both "ABC", but not able to find the highest amount from these two strings. Please help me if any one knows the answer.

Comment: What is the highest amount of a String?

Comment: pls format the code properl

Comment: Post some code and tell us  what you've tried so far!

Comment: Your question is unclear. You split the string based on "ABC"? Then you'd have an array like so: `["", "|123|5.00|#", "|567|10.00"]`... this doesn't look useful to me. Did you mean to split by "#" instead? Some code would help diagnose the issue much better.

Comment: String str = "ABC|123|5.00|#ABC|567|10.00|#ABC|567|15.00"; These are 3 strings and combined together. Amount field is "5.00","10.00","15.00". I have to find the highest amount from these 3 strings

Comment: It's time to encapsulate this into an object.  Splitting the strings around like this is nightmarish at best.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the strings by 
`String [] s = str.split("#");`
then create for value a 
`String [] values1 = s[0].split("|")`(do this for value b)
now cast them to float and compare them. finish.

Comment: String str = "ABC|123|5.00|#ABC|567|10.00|#ABC|567|10.00";
String word = "ABC";
int x = 0,y = 0,z = 0;
 for (int j = -1; (j = str.indexOf(word, j + 1)) != -1;) {    
  x = j;
 if (x != y) {
   z = y;  
   System.out.println(z + " && " + x);
 }
   y = x; 
     
        } I got the 3 indexes of "ABC", (0,14,29). Now I have to read the strings from 0,14 , 14,29 ,&& 29 to last position, then take the highest amount from these three strings. I am stuck at the last part. To get these strings based on indexes and to get the highest amount.

Comment: could you rewrite your question with that, and explain the things ... (index, highest amount, ...)